# Elegant way to check loop invariant

Tags: java, invariants, loop-invariant

I learned that the loop invariant should be true before the loop, at the start of the loop body, at the end of the loop body and after the loop. This 4 points can be reduced to 2 points if there are no side effects of the condition: **Before the loop and at the end of the loop body.** Here is an example in Java where I check the invariant with `assert`:

```
private static int cube(int n) {
    int t = 1;
    int s = 0;
    int i = 0;

    assert (s == i*i*i && t == (i-1)*(i-1) && i <= n);

    while (i < n) {
        t = t + 2*i - 1;
        s = s + 3*t + 3*i + 1;
        i++;
        assert (s == i*i*i && t == (i-1)*(i-1) && i <= n);
    }

    return s;
}
```

I think the redundancy of the invariant expression is pretty bad. If Java would let me do this, the asserts could be reduced to **one single assertion** point before the condition.

```
while ( i < n)
       ^
```

So I came up with another conceptual solution and splitted the condition into another method:

```
private static int cubeElegant(int n){
    int t = 1;
    int s = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (condition(n, t, s, i)){
        t = t + 2*i - 1;
        s = s + 3*t + 3*i + 1;
        i++;
    }

    return s;
}

private static boolean condition(int n, int t, int s, int i){
    assert (s == i*i*i && t == (i-1)*(i-1) && i <= n);
    return i < n;
}
```

I think the readability is pretty bad and the code is unnecessarily bloated. Is my solution a possible way to implement somehow a design by contract invariant check without the use of third party libraries? Is there another much more elegant way in Java?

Comment: The readability is bad because you have meaningless variable names and plenty of magic numbers. Other than that, moving the check to a function is good.

Comment: @Michael Maybe it is a bad example when it comes to redable code but I tried to reduce it to a minimum so everybody can focus on the actual difficulty.